# Обработка touch-событий на canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5, canvas, touch-event

Есть простое приложение типа paint. Не получается рисовать на холсте с помощью тач-дисплея на телефоне и планшете.
Может, есть CSS атрибут?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А что мешает прочитать [офф документацию](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Touch_events)? Там и пример с канвасом есть

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="600" style="border:solid black 1px;">
  Ваш браузер не поддерживает элемент canvas.
</canvas>
<br>
<button onclick="startup()">Инициализировать</button>

function startup() {
  var el = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];
  el.addEventListener("touchstart", handleStart, false);
  el.addEventListener("touchend", handleEnd, false);
  el.addEventListener("touchcancel", handleCancel, false);
  el.addEventListener("touchmove", handleMove, false);
  log("initialized.");
}
```

Где `handleStart`, `handleEnd` ... и т.д. обработчики касаний